# Mysql database restoring with fab and curses in django

Tags: mysql, django, curses, floating-action-button

```
@hosts(['localhost'])
def start():
    import curses
    screen = curses.initscr()
    backup_file = db_backup.sql
    local("mysql -u %s -p %s < " % (
        db_username,db_name) + backup_file)
```

now I run this with **fab start**

it asks for a password, after I entered the password the screen is not responding.

Can anyone know what's happening here? if I remove curses it is working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By suspending the curses, it will return to the terminal. where we can complete the restore database task.

Answer (score 0):

The `local` command is doing the prompt for the password.  That expects that the terminal modes are set normally, so that if you press <kbd>Enter</kbd> (which sends a `^M`) it is mapped into a newline (`^J`).

When you initialized curses using `curses.initscr`, that changes the terminal modes so that the mapping is not done.  The curses library does its *own* mapping when you call `getch`.

If you press <kbd>control</kbd><kbd>J</kbd> rather than <kbd>Enter</kbd>, that should appease the password prompt in the `local` command.

Since your example is not using curses (perhaps it does *later*) you can either omit it, or move the initialization down to the place where you need to use it.

In any case, you probably cannot make the `local` command use a password prompt in the script via curses (without assuming and relying upon special devices).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I found the solution for it. I just suspend the curses before calling the local command with curses.endwin().